# neuralnet output call in R

Tags: r, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I've been working with neuralnet in R to assist in generating predictions for state classified outcomes.
Two days ago, I managed to generate a different sort of output that looked something like this (see attached photo).
Then my hard drive crashed, and I lost that line of code.
Can someone help me replicate this function??
Thanks.
[screenshot neuralnet output in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56zJ0.png)
the ultimate output of the call was:
a 2-3-1 network with 13 weights
options were - decay=0.1
b->h1 i1->h1 i2->h1
0.02  -0.03   0.04
b->h2 i1->h2 i2->h2
0.05   0.01  -0.03
b->h3 i1->h3 i2->h3
-0.05  -0.02   0.01
b->o h1->o h2->o h3->o
-1.07  0.00 -1.08 -0.08

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Recovered my lost code.
This is the call:

model <- train(statetrans~., data=trainset2, method='nnet',
trControl=trainControl(method='cv'))